# Use ng-token-auth toghether with typeahead/bloodhound

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the Angular.js project, where I use [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) for user authentication, I want to integrate [Twitter Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

I have constructed a directive, where the content of the link function is:

```
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
        hs_list = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('hs8'),
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          remote: 'api/trainings/hs_list?q=%QUERY'
        })
        hs_list.initialize()
        element.typeahead(null, {
          name: 'hs-mapping-id',
          displayKey: 'hs8',
          source: hs_list.ttAdapter(),
          templates: {
            empty: [
              '<div class="empty-message">',
              'We cannot find this training',
              '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p class="clearfix"><strong>{{hs8}}</strong> &mdash; {{hs8_text}}<br /><span style="display:inline-block; height: 22px; overflow: hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; max-width: 400px;">{{hs6_text}}</span></p>')
          }
        })
        .bind( 'typeahead:opened', ->
          $(this).data('ttTypeahead').dropdown.$menu.addClass('overflow-hidden').perfectScrollbar()
        )
        .on 'keyup', ->
          $(this).data('ttTypeahead').dropdown.$menu.perfectScrollbar('update')
```

When I try to use it, I get the unauthorized access redirection, because the auth headers are missing from Bloodhound requests. What is the way to add auth headers to the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found an answer!

ng-token-auth provides a helper, which returns headers for [ajax settings object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings):

> $auth.retrieveData('auth_headers')

So in order to use it with Bloodhound, all we need to do is:

```
angular.module('app').directive 'trainingsList', ($auth) ->
    return {
      restrict: 'A'
      link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
        hs_list = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('hs8'),
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          remote:
            url: 'api/trainings/hs_list?q=%QUERY'
            ajax:
              headers: $auth.retrieveData('auth_headers')

        })
        hs_list.initialize()
        element.typeahead(null, {
          name: 'hs-mapping-id',
          displayKey: 'hs8',
          source: hs_list.ttAdapter(),
          templates: {
            empty: [
              '<div class="empty-message">',
              'We cannot find this training',
              '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p class="clearfix"><strong>{{hs8}}</strong> &mdash; {{hs8_text}}<br /><span style="display:inline-block; height: 22px; overflow: hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; max-width: 400px;">{{hs6_text}}</span></p>')
          }
        })
        .bind( 'typeahead:opened', ->
          $(this).data('ttTypeahead').dropdown.$menu.addClass('overflow-hidden').perfectScrollbar()
        )
        .on 'keyup', ->
          $(this).data('ttTypeahead').dropdown.$menu.perfectScrollbar('update')
    };
```